# Is there a non-microsoft / open-source MVC framework for ASP.net?

Tags: model-view-controller, open-source, alt.net

I have seen in the past that before MS takes a dash at something, there is awareness in the .net community for it already. I am talking here about the ALT NET and Open Source folks who are like " If MS has come up with Entity Framework, we have NHibernate ". I was just wondering if an MVC framework exits that is worth looking at which is not built by MS.

Is there any? Is it microsoft's moment to be the first to come up with something like it ?

Comment: Last time I checked Alt.Net is not Anti-Microsoft. They just go with which ever solutions make the most sense. NHibernate for example is more mature and has all the features that people wanted from an o/rm solution that Entity framework lacks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[MonoRail](http://www.castleproject.org/MonoRail/) (existed before the official MVC project)

[FubuMVC](http://code.google.com/p/fubumvc/) (created after, still in early stages)

Also, if you're not tied to the Microsoft platform there are tons of others: Ruby on Rails, CakePHP, [Django](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/general/#django-appears-to-be-a-mvc-framework-but-you-call-the-controller-the-view-and-the-view-the-template-how-come-you-don-t-use-the-standard-names), Spring (Java) and more.

Comment: oops, thanks for fixing the link

Comment: I am a big fan of Django and use it for my side projects. I have not fallen in love with Ruby. Languages with begin- end as keywords never really appealed me, specially coming from a Python background. +1

Answer (score 1):

There's also [ProMesh.NET](http://www.codeplex.com/ProMesh)

Answer (score 1):

If you think of an open source MVC, try Microsoft's ASP.Net MVC.
It is opened under Microsoft Public License (source: [Heise Newsticker, German](http://www.heise.de/newsticker/Microsofts-ASP-Net-MVC-Projekt-wird-Open-Source--/meldung/135655) and [ScottGu's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/04/01/asp-net-mvc-1-0.aspx)).

Probably it helps :)

Comment: it wasnt a trick question :) but +1 anyway for the links

Comment: I thought it would be nice to know :)

Answer (score -3):

Microsoft completely ripped Monorail...I think they even hired the head developer (of MonoRail) to work on the MVC.Net project as well

Comment: was it Phil Haack or Steven Walthers ?

Comment: Ripping monorail is debatable. Hiring the head developer on the castle project is true http://hammett.castleproject.org/?p=312

Comment: Yes, hiring the head developer on the Castle project is true.  However, he has not been involved at all with the development of ASP.NET MVC, hence my earlier comment.

Comment: Levi is correct. Hamilton is currently working on the MEF team (if I recall). The ASP.NET MVC team does look at things like Ruby on Rails, MonoRail, Django, and other MVC frameworks but not maliciously so. Phil Haack is good people.